# I was updating my firmware for my 400XL kit for Ender 3 Pro and got an original firmware from the Creality website, but VSCode couldn't read it

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, file-formats, microsd, 400xl

Basically,

- I got the XL
- I installed the kit
- I downloaded the firmware from the Marlin GitHub page (Version 1.1.9 for Ender 3 Pro v2)
- I put it in VSCode but it says that it is not binary or uses unsupported text so VSCode can't even show me what is going on.

Question:

1. How can I make it into a supported text or read it?
2. Did I do it right using this method?
3. If not, what is my next option?

Answer (score 1):

What exact firmware did you download? One of the ".bin" files? Those are already compiled and can not be edited, you'll need to download one in .zip format, where the whole Marlin "configuration.h" etc. structure is present.
Except for the very last option on their download page ("Ender-3 Pro_1.1.6.2V_Source Code.zip"), all files (illegaly) only contain the .bin or .hex files.

1.1.9 is ancient and obsolete.

It's probably a good idea to download a fresh copy of up-to-date Marlin (https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin) and copy over the correct configuration files from https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/tree/import-2.0.x/config/examples/Creality/Ender-3%20Pro to get you started.